# Unable to create instance of POJO service

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio

I am new to Mule and I am trying to solve below error in java class.

Below is my java class:

```
package com.eb.mule;

import java.sql.Timestamp;


import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;

import com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet;

import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

import com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException;

import com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs;

public class CassandraInsert {

private static CassandraInsert _instance;
protected static Cluster cluster;
protected static Session session;

private String hostname = "My ip address";
private int port = myportnumber;

public static synchronized CassandraInsert getInstance() {
    if (_instance == null) {
        _instance = new CassandraInsert();
    }
    return _instance;
}

public CassandraInsert() {**
    try{
        cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(hostname).withPort(port).build();
        session = cluster.connect();                 
    } catch (NoHostAvailableException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }       
    System.out.println("connected to cluster");
}

public static Cluster getCluster() {
    return cluster;
}

public static Session getSession() {
    return session;
}



public String insertSensorData(Integer component, Integer measurement, Timestamp datetime, Double sensorvalue) {

    //Builder builder = Cluster.builder();
    //Cluster cluster = builder.addContactPoint("myipaddress").withPort(portnumber).build();
    //Session session = cluster.connect();


    StringBuilder insertString = new StringBuilder();

    UUIDs uuid = new com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs();

    insertString.append("insert into dm.data (component_id, measurement_id, snapshot, value) values(")
    .append(component)
    .append(", ")
    .append(measurement)
    .append(", ")
    .append(uuid.startOf(datetime.getTime()))
    .append(", '")
    .append(sensorvalue)
    .append("');");

    ResultSet result;
    try {
        result = session.execute(insertString.toString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    //session.shutdown();
    //cluster.shutdown();

    return "data loaded:  measurement_id: " + measurement  + " Component_id: " + component + " Snapshot: " + datetime + " Value: " + sensorvalue;
}
```

}

My console is showing below errors...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentStartException: ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.transport.FrameCompressor
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:170)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.start(ApplicationWrapper.java:107)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:48)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:127)


Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Unable to create instance of POJO service
    at org.mule.component.DefaultJavaComponent.doStart(DefaultJavaComponent.java:76)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$4.onTransition(AbstractComponent.java:313)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$4.onTransition(AbstractComponent.java:308)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:141)
    at org.mule.component.ComponentLifecycleManager.fireStartPhase(ComponentLifecycleManager.java:71)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.start(AbstractComponent.java:307)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.start(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:94)
    at org.mule.routing.MessageProcessorFilterPair.start(MessageProcessorFilterPair.java:105)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.start(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:114)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractMuleObjectOwner.start(AbstractMuleObjectOwner.java:78)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractMuleObjectOwner.start(AbstractMuleObjectOwner.java:78)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.start(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:94)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.startIfStartable(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:326)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doStart(AbstractPipeline.java:310)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$2.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:145)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$2.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:141)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:141)
    at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireStartPhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:95)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.start(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:225)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager$RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:276)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:155)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:126)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:80)
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:120)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:94)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:90)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:72)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:64)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:255)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:147)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: null
    at org.mule.object.SingletonObjectFactory.getInstance(SingletonObjectFactory.java:85)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.createLifecycleAdaptor(AbstractJavaComponent.java:112)
    at org.mule.component.DefaultJavaComponent.doStart(DefaultJavaComponent.java:71)
    ... 37 more


Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cassandra/transport/FrameCompressor
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.<init>(Cluster.java:288)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.builder(Cluster.java:107)
    at com.eb.mule.CassandraInsert.<init>(CassandraInsert.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:412)
    at org.mule.object.AbstractObjectFactory.getInstance(AbstractObjectFactory.java:136)
    at org.mule.object.SingletonObjectFactory.getInstance(SingletonObjectFactory.java:81)
    ... 39 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.transport.FrameCompressor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.findClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:179)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleApplicationClassLoader.findClass(MuleApplicationClassLoader.java:144)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.loadClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:123)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleApplicationClassLoader.loadClass(MuleApplicationClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 49 more
```

I just added: **cassandra-driver-core-1.0.2**, **MySQL** and **PostgreSQL** jar files.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the dependency/jar that contains class FrameCompressor. I think it is `cassandra-all`.